# Error in addWorksheet

Tags: r

I'm trying to save data in an existing Excel sheet:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook("MyLink")
addWorksheet(wb, "Results 2018")
```

and I keep getting this error:

> ```
> Error in createWorkbook("MyLink") : 
>   Unknown format MyLink
> ```

Friend of mine run the same thing on his computer and it works for him just fine.

Comment: you need to create like that https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.0.0/topics/createWorkbook

Comment: The parameter to `createWorkbook` is the creator of the workbook, not its name. What happens if you call this function with no parameters?

Comment: My friend is the one one who created the first excel file, so when he add the tab it works for him but me as I'm not the creator of the excel , i get the error ... Is that what you mean @s-brunel

Comment: The code `createWorkbook("MyLink")` creates a new workbook object owned by the user `"MyLink"`. Perhaps you want the function `loadWorkbook` to load an existing workbook?